# Changing tab bar background color causes all screens to re-render

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation` as my navigation solution. I need to change the background color of my tab bar on click of a button in the `settings` screen, however, do so would make all screens re-render, here's a live demo of what's going on:

[image]

As you can see, every time I press the `Change Tab Bar Background Color` button in `Settings` screen, the color of the tab bar changes, however, at the same time, the app automatically navigates to `Login` screen for some reason. I am using `redux` to maintain the current theme, here are the code:

Action creator:

```
export function switchTheme() {
    return { type: 'SWITCH_THEME' };
}
```

Reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    backgroundColor: 'white'
};

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SWITCH_THEME':
            return { backgroundColor: state.backgroundColor === 'white' ? 'black' : 'white'  };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Settings screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { switchTheme } from '../actions';

class SettingsScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Settings',
        header: null,
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
            return (<Icon name='settings' size={30} color={tintColor} />);
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ ... }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.props.switchTheme}
                    style={{ ... }}
                >
                    <Text style={{ ... }}>
                        Change Tab Bar Background Color
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, { switchTheme })(SettingsScreen);
```

Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './screens/RegisterScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';
import MessageScreen from './screens/MessageScreen';

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        const MainTabNavigator = TabNavigator({
            login: { screen: LoginScreen },
            register: { screen: RegisterScreen },
            message: { screen: MessageScreen },
            setting: { screen: SettingsScreen }
        }, {
            tabBarOptions: {
                style: { backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor }
            }
        });

        return (
            <MainTabNavigator />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { backgroundColor } = state.theme;
    return { backgroundColor };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Main);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './store';

import Main from './Main';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Main />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Why does the app navigates to `Login` screen and what can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: refer this :  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026608/react-native-change-background-color-in-tabnavigator-dynamically/49051862#49051862](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026608/react-native-change-background-color-in-tabnavigator-dynamically/49051862#49051862)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the backgroundcolor piece of state is changed in the reducer SWITCH_THEME 
so I think when it comes to the  main.js and  pull out the backgroundColor from state.theme  the prop backgroundColor gets updated and it re-renders