# React Native - Change background color in tabnavigator dynamically

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

i want to change my tab navigator background color dynamically in based on my API response so below is my code

**_TabNavigator.js**

```
const MyTabnav = TabNavigator({
ScreenOne: {
    screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => <ScreenOneNav screenProps={{ tabbarNavigation: navigation, ...screenProps }} onNavigationStateChange={null} />,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'ScreenOne',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <View style={[styles.tabViewBox]}>
                 <Text style={[styles.tabText, { color: tintColor }]}>ScreenOne</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
},
ScreenTwo: {
    screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => <ScreenOneNav screenProps={{ tabbarNavigation: navigation, ...screenProps, }} onNavigationStateChange={null} />,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'ScreenOne',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <View style={[styles.tabViewBox]}>
                <Text style={[styles.tabText, { color: tintColor }]}>ScreenTwo</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
},
ScreenThree: {
    screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => <StockNotificationNav screenProps={{ tabbarNavigation: navigation, ...screenProps }} onNavigationStateChange={null} />,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Notifications',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <View style={[styles.tabViewBox]}>
                 <Text style={[styles.tabText, { color: tintColor }]}>ScreenThree</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
},
},
 {

    tabBarOptions: {

        style: {
            backgroundColor: white,
            height: 55,
            borderTopColor: 'transparent',
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            paddingRight: 10,
            paddingLeft: 10,
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            borderTopColor: grayPlaceHolder
        },
        showLabel: false,
        showIcon : true,
    },
    tabBarComponent : TabBarBottom,

    initialRouteName: 'ScreenTwo',
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false
}, []);


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
tabText: {
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: "600",
    flex: 4,
},
tabViewBox: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
},
 tabIcon: {
    flex: 5,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: 10
  },
});
export default StocksTabNav;
```

I want to change my tabnavigtor background color in my ScreenTwo.js file which include API response code on it as per that it tabnavigator background color **(backgroundColor)** should change as black or white as per API response so how can i achieve this? your all suggestions are appreciable

**After update code as per Rahul suggests give below warning message**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you can do is make one custom tabBar component and using javaScript immutability concept you can override style of tabBarOptions.

```js
     const MyTabnav = TabNavigator({ScreenOne: {
        screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => <ScreenOneNav screenProps={{ tabbarNavigation: navigation, ...screenProps }} onNavigationStateChange={null} />,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'ScreenOne',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <View style={[styles.tabViewBox]}>
                     <Text style={[styles.tabText, { color: tintColor }]}>ScreenOne</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
    },
    ScreenTwo: {
        screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => <ScreenOneNav screenProps={{ tabbarNavigation: navigation, ...screenProps, }} onNavigationStateChange={null} />,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'ScreenOne',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <View style={[styles.tabViewBox]}>
                    <Text style={[styles.tabText, { color: tintColor }]}>ScreenTwo</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
    },
    ScreenThree: {
        screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => <StockNotificationNav screenProps={{ tabbarNavigation: navigation, ...screenProps }} onNavigationStateChange={null} />,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Notifications',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <View style={[styles.tabViewBox]}>
                     <Text style={[styles.tabText, { color: tintColor }]}>ScreenThree</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
    },
    },
     {

        tabBarOptions: {

            style: {
                backgroundColor: white,
                height: 55,
                borderTopColor: 'transparent',
                borderTopWidth: 1,
                paddingRight: 10,
                paddingLeft: 10,
                borderTopWidth: 1,
                borderTopColor: grayPlaceHolder
            },
            showLabel: false,


         showIcon : true,
        },

//Here Goes Your CustomTabBar Component 
        tabBarComponent : CustomTabBarComponent,
        initialRouteName: 'ScreenTwo',
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        animationEnabled: false,
        swipeEnabled: false
    }, []);
```

**CustomTabBarComponent.js**

```js
     const TabBar = (props) => {
          const { navigationState } = props;
          let newProps = props;

            newProps = Object.assign(
              {},
              props,
              {
                style: {

         // get value from redux store and set it here 
                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
                  position: 'absolute',
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0
                },
                activeTintColor: '#fff',
                inactiveTintColor: '#bbb',
              },
            );


          return <TabBarBottom {...newProps} />;
        };
```

Now You can connect this CustomTabBarComponent with Redux store and can change the value of whatever Property you want.

Comment: where exactly are you getting the error? without seeing your code it's difficult to know what's going wrong. if you tried exactly this same code, it wouldn't give you an error. it's working for me even with redux integrated.

Comment: Okay let me try this scenario again.

Comment: in may case ScreenOne is stack navigator , from that stacknavigators first screen i want to change tabnavigators color , what should i do? I am using createMaterialBottomtabnavigator

Comment: I tried this scenario, background color is working but my tab bar doesn’t showing any tabs. Its showing a simple view with backgorund color. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is set your tab component as a function and send the color as a parameter to that function. Try this:

```js
const MyTabnav = color => TabNavigator({
    ScreenOne: {
        screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => <ScreenOneNav screenProps={{ tabbarNavigation: navigation, ...screenProps }} onNavigationStateChange={null} />,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'ScreenOne',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <View style={[styles.tabViewBox]}>
                    <Text style={[styles.tabText, { color: tintColor }]}>ScreenOne</Text>
                </View>
             )
        }
    },
    ScreenTwo: {
        screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => <ScreenOneNav screenProps={{ tabbarNavigation: navigation, ...screenProps, }} onNavigationStateChange={null} />,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'ScreenOne',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <View style={[styles.tabViewBox]}>
                   <Text style={[styles.tabText, { color: tintColor }]}>ScreenTwo</Text>
                </View>
             )
        }
    },
    ScreenThree: {
        screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => <StockNotificationNav screenProps={{ tabbarNavigation: navigation, ...screenProps }} onNavigationStateChange={null} />,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Notifications',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <View style={[styles.tabViewBox]}>
                     <Text style={[styles.tabText, { color: tintColor }]}>ScreenThree</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
    },
},
{

    tabBarOptions: {
        //use the color you passed in the prop here:
        style: {
            backgroundColor: color,
            height: 55,
            borderTopColor: 'transparent',
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            paddingRight: 10,
            paddingLeft: 10,
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            borderTopColor: grayPlaceHolder
        },
        showLabel: false,
        showIcon : true,
    },
    tabBarComponent : TabBarBottom,

    initialRouteName: 'ScreenTwo',
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false
    }, []);


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    tabText: {
        fontSize: 10,
        fontWeight: "600",
        flex: 4,
    },
    tabViewBox: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    tabIcon: {
        flex: 5,
        alignSelf: "center",
        marginTop: 10
    },
});
export default MyTabNav;
```

Then where you use `MyTabnav` pass the color as a param to it.  for example

```js
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            color: 'black'
        };
    }
    getRandomColor = () => {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    };
    onPress = () => {
        this.setState({
            color: this.getRandomColor()
        });
    };
    render() {
        const Tabs = MyTabnav(this.state.color);
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Button onPress={this.onPress} title="Click me" />
                <Tabs />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but i get warning message screen as per above check my question part

Comment: Have you initialized your tab component like this: `const Tabs = MyTabnav(this.state.color);`

Comment: Yes i initialize it in my child js file

Comment: [https://pastebin.com/S7Vk8XmN](https://pastebin.com/S7Vk8XmN) Check this link, i tried like this, when i try with this code i get blank white screen and give above yellow warning screen

Comment: StocksTabNav  is same which i mention in my question as MyTabnav , there are no any change in code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166178/discussion-between-rahul-and-harshal-kalavadiya).

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
const tabBarOptions = {
// setting height 'null', and top 0 will change the color of pressed tab
   indicatorStyle: {
     height: null,
     top: 0,
     backgroundColor: "red",
     borderBottomColor: "black",
     borderBottomWidth: 3,
   },
   activeTintColor: "black",
   pressColor: "white",
   style: {
     backgroundColor: "#ddc8be",
   },
   labelStyle: { fontSize: 13 },
};
```