# activebackgroundcolor of tabbaroptions in react native bottom tab

Tags: react-native

I have used react native bottom tab bar in which i want to set activebackgroundcolor of tab bar options dynamic according to theme of project.It doesnt change once set to default colour.Any idea how to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - Change background color in tabnavigator dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026608/react-native-change-background-color-in-tabnavigator-dynamically)

Comment: Thanks but no solution work i have tried all available here at stack related to it

Comment: solved it myself!